# magento wont save category, when i press save just nothing happens

Tags: magento, save, categories

I want to make a store in my magento website.
To make a store you need a root category but when i want to make a root category it wont save.
I have set all the setting correctly and then when i hit "save category" just nothing happens.

Comment: check for any log errors

Comment: i have enabled logs and it doesnt create a log file

Comment: no everything is reindexed from the last error you helped me with

Comment: check whether controller is triggering. `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController::saveAction()`. put `die();` there.

Comment: where actually do i need to put that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60091/discussion-between-djeroen-and-programmer-rkt).

Comment: Have you assigned the root category to the store? Admin->System->Manage Stores.